# BAT/POWERSHELL copy (only)yesterday files

Tags: powershell, batch-file, copy, timestamp

I'm trying to write some script to copy all files which have been created yesterday (only!)

/D parameter for xcopy means copy files changed on or after the specified date so its not what i'm searching for. Any ideas? ;/

Comment: have you tried something and faced a specific problem or are you just asking for working code?

Comment: FORFILES -p E:\test /d -1 -m *.txt -c "CMD /C XCOPY E:\test\@FILE E:\test\123" (it's yesterday & older) c:\windows\system32\xcopy.exe E:\test\*.txt E:\test\123\ /s /f /y /d:04-07-2015 (it's yesterday and later) i have no idea how to get only yesterday files

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use powershell. You can use `Get-ChildItem` and `Where-Object` to get the list of files created the day before

```
$yesterdayFiles = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Date -eq ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date)}
```

Then you can copy the files stored in `$yesterdayFiles` variable using `Copy-Item` cmdlets

Answer (score 1):

I've tried with **robocopy /minage:1 /maxage:1**  but seems does not work.But work when I set the current date.Here's the script (you'll need to set your source and destination):

```
@echo off

set "source=C:\folder1"
set "dest=C:\folder2"

pushd "%temp%"
::get cirrent date
makecab /D RptFileName=~.rpt /D InfFileName=nul /f nul >nul
for /f "tokens=3-7" %%a in ('find /i "makecab"^<~.rpt') do (
   set "year=%%e"
   set "mon=%%b"
   set "day=%%c"

)
del ~.*
popd
:: convert month to numeric string
for %%a in (
    "Jan-01" "Feb-02" "Mar-03" "Apr-04" "May-05" "Jun-06" "Jul-07" "Aug-08" "Sep-09" "Oct-10" "Nov-11" "Dec-12"
) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%x in ("%%~a") do (
        if "%mon%" equ "%%x" (
            set "mon=%%y"
            goto :skip
        )
    )
)
:skip
set "c_date=%year%%mon%%day%"
::echo %c_date%

:: is switch is for force overwriting
robocopy "%source%" "%dest%" * /maxage:1 /minage:%c_date% /is
```

robocopy is built-in every windows since Vista.If your are running under XP or Vista you'll need to download it from microsoft site.

Answer (score 1):

This Batch file selects all files that were created on the same date *before today*. If you are sure that there are files created yesterday, then it solve your problem.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "yesterday="
for /F "skip=5 tokens=1,4*" %%a in ('dir /TC /O-D /A-D') do (
   if "%%a" neq "%date%" (
      if not defined yesterday set "yesterday=%%a"
      if "%%a" equ "!yesterday!" (
         echo Created yesterday: %%a "%%c"
      ) else (
         goto break
      )
   )
)
:break
```